# PlayOnLinux Steam Stalls

Tags: games, playonlinux

I tried using PlayOnLinux. 
I downloaded my game, no problems. 
When I click PLAY, nothing happens. A loading screen from steam flashes up, less than half a second, then nothing.

The first time I clicked PLAY it had a 'preparing to launch for the first time' or some such message. It froze for a bit then cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add as a comment, why are you using playonlinux? Steam has a native client. `sudo apt-get install steam`

Comment: It doesn't work for most games. Only a handful... not mine.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: First off, I'm a noob...
I open steam, it doesn't even let me install games onto ubuntu, never mind play them. Says they're incompatible with my os.